# OperationalError at /admin/blog/comments/ no such column: blog_comments.post_id

Tags: python, django, model, migrate

I have a site and wanted to add comment to it. I wrote the model for comments and a FK to the posts model. There was a problem that I understood after migrating I tried deleting the migration files and then faking the migration but didn't help. when migrating I get this error:
**django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "blog_posts" already exists**

and when entering the admin panel and go to comment section I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg00G.png)

I tried deleting the migration files and then faking the migration but didn't help.
this is my models:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class Comments(models.Model):
        post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments',blank=True,null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=80,default='neda')
        body = models.TextField(default="add here")


        def __str__(self):
            return self.post
```

Comment: Well one easy way out is to delete the db and run the migrations again. The first error is because you are running migrations that already have been ran and the second error is because the migration that contains the post id has not been ran

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when you create table in DB and add field later!
New fields must be allowed null equal True ..
clear your Sqlite then make migrations and migrate tables .